# Insertar relación Muchos a Muchos entre 2 tablas pre cargadas pasando solo ID en JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con SpringMVC + Hibernate, y me gustaría saber como insertar una relación entre 2 tablas que ya cuentan con registros cargados pasando solo el ID de cada Entidad, por ejemplo:

Tenemos la Tabla Personas con la siguiente información

```
ID | NOMBRES | APELLIDOS
1  | Pers1   | Apell 1
2  | Pers2   | Apell 2
```

y la tabla GRUPOS

```
ID | NOMB_GRUPO
1  | Grupo 1
2  | Grupo 2
```

Toda esa información ya esta precargada en la Base de datos. Y ambas tablas tienen una relacion n:m, por lo que tenemos una tabla intermedia PERSONAS_GRUPOS.
Intento realizar esto:

```
Personas pers = new Personas();
pers.setID(1);
pers.getGrupos().add(1);
pers.getGrupos().add(2);
```

Y ejecuto en EntityManager de esta forma:

```
em = getEM();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(pers);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close()
```

Y no me inserta la relacion manytomany. Sino que me lanza error de que tengo campos null, ya que solo le paso el id de la clase y no todo el contenido.

(editado) Acá dejo un ejemplo de la estructura actual de mis Entidades:

```
public class Grupos implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idGrupos

    private String descripcion

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "personas_grupos",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "idGrupos"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "idPersonas")
    )
    private Set<Personas> pers= new HashSet<>();

    getters and setters ....
}

public class Personas implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idPersonas;
    private String Nombres
    private String Apellidos

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy="funcionarios")
    private transient Set<Grupos> group=new HashSet();

    getters and setters ....
}
```

(editado 19-08-2019) Para que se entienda mejor lo que necesito, me gustaría agregar una información mas como ejemplo:

Yo tengo una vista de lo que sería la TABLA de GRUPOS, en esta vista solo se representa toda la información del GRUPO seleccionado (Ej. Info Grupo1), no así de los demás grupos. Dentro de esta vista tengo una tabla en donde voy cargando el ID y Nombre de las personas que voy agregando a este GRUPO (Todo esto consultando desde la Base de Datos a través de una búsqueda).

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que al presionar el boton guardar, me capture el ID de las personas que están dentro de la GRILLA y que en base a ese ID me inserte las personas en la relación N:M de la Base de datos.

Esto ya lo pude solucionar creando una NativeQuery, solo quisiera saber si es posible realizar lo mismo utilizando la anotación @ManyToMany de JPA.

Por si a alguien le sirva dejo aquí el método que utilice para insertar la relación en la BD:

```
public boolean insertPersonasGrupos(Integer idGroup, JsonArray Personas){
        boolean valid = false;
        try {
            em = getEM();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Integer idGrupo = idGroup;
            for (int i=0; i<Personas.size();i++){
                  JsonObject pers = new Gson().fromJson(Personas.get(i), JsonObject.class);
                  String queryString2 = "INSERT INTO personas_grupos(id_grupos, id_personas) values (?,?)";
                  Query query2 = em.createNativeQuery(queryString2);
                    query2.setParameter(1, idGrupo);
                    query2.setParameter(2, pers.get("id").getAsInt());
                    query2.executeUpdate();
              }
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            valid = true;
            return valid;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return valid;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Échale un ojo a esta página de como manejar Set y HashSet:
https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=610:interfaces-set-y-sortedset-del-api-java-clases-hashset-y-treeset-ordenado-ejemplo-diferencias-cu00924c&catid=58&Itemid=180

Yo tampoco se del manejo de estas clases, pero he buscado y ese artículo está genial.
Miraste que no haya restricciones Not Null en la base de datos para construir omitiendo campos?

///Intento que me ha funcionado. 
He hecho un supuesto en un IDE para el movil y me guarda bien.
Creé la clase Personas:

```
package src;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Personas {

  private int id;
  private String nombre;
  private String apellidos;
  private Set<Grupos> grupos = new HashSet<>();

  public Personas(){

  }
  public Personas(int id, String nombre, String apellidos){
     this.id = id;
     this.nombre = nombre;
     this.apellidos = apellidos;

  }

  public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getId(){
     return id;
  }

  public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
  }

  public void setApellidos(String apellidos){
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
  }

  public String getApellidos(){
    return apellidos;
  }

  public void setGrupos(Grupos grupo){
    grupos.add(grupo);
  }

  public Set<Grupos> getGrupos(){
    return grupos;
  }
}
```

Creé la clase Grupos:

```
 package src;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Grupos {

   private int idGrupos;
   private String nombreGrupos;
   private Set<Personas> personas = new HashSet<>();


  public Grupos(){

  }
  public Grupos(int idGrupos, String nombreGrupos){
     this.idGrupos = idGrupos;
     this.nombreGrupos = nombreGrupos;
  }

  public void setIdGrupos(int idGrupos){
     this.idGrupos = idGrupos;
  }

  public int getIdGrupos(){
    return idGrupos;
  }

  public void setNombreGrupos(String nombreGrupos){
    this.nombreGrupos = nombreGrupos;
  }

  public String getNombreGrupos(){

    return nombreGrupos;
  }

  public void setPersonas(Personas persona){
    personas.add(persona);
  }

  public Set<Personas> getPersonas(){
    return personas;
  }
}
```

Y la clase donde implemento el método main:

```
package src;

import java.util.Set;

public class PruebaSet {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Personas pers1 = new Personas(1, "nombre1", "apellidos1");
    Personas pers2 = new Personas(2, "nombre2", "apellidos2");
    Personas pers3 = new Personas(3, "nombre3", "apellidos3");
    Personas pers4 = new Personas(4, "nombre4", "apellidos4");
    Grupos grups1 = new Grupos(1, "grupos1");
    Grupos grups2 = new Grupos(2, "grupos2");
    pers1.setGrupos(grups1);
    pers2.setGrupos(grups1);
    pers2.setGrupos(grups2);
    pers3.setGrupos(grups2);
    pers4.setGrupos(grups1);
    grups1.setPersonas(pers1);
    grups1.setPersonas(pers2);
    grups1.setPersonas(pers4);
    grups2.setPersonas(pers2);
    grups2.setPersonas(pers3);

    System.out.println("Grupos a los que pertenece " + pers2.getNombre() + ":");

    Set<Grupos> grupos = pers2.getGrupos();
    for(Grupos g : grupos){
       System.out.println(g.getNombreGrupos());
    } 

    System.out.println("Personas que pertenecen a " + grups1.getNombreGrupos() + ":");

    Set<Personas> personas = grups1.getPersonas();
     for(Personas p : personas){
       System.out.println(p.getNombre());
     }
 } 
}
```

Y el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/169417)

Comment: Gracias. Cambiado.

Comment: Esta respuesta me fue bastante útil, el problema esta de que esto funciona muy bien para agregar nuevos registros. En mi caso la tabla personas y la tabla grupos ya tienen valores guardados. Lo que no estoy pudiendo hacer es unir esos valores en una relacion n:m pasando todo el ID. Quizá no se pueda con JPA, al parecer requiere que tenga toda la Entidad cargada antes de hacer el merge en la BD, por eso me valida los campos nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Yo también soy nuevo en esto. Así que aporto lo que puedo o como yo lo veo. 
Creo que si está creada la Persona y no tienes ningun método implementado que te busque por id o algo así, estás creando una persona con el id duplicado. 
Otra opcion es que mapees y crees el pojo de PERSONAS_GRUPOS
Y con un constructor simple, como has hecho con Personas, crees un objeto tipo PersonasGrupos. 
Y despues con sus sets asignas persona y grupo. 
Algo así:

```
PersonasGrupos personasGrupos = new PersonasGrupos();
personasGrupos.setPersonaId(1);
personasGrupos.setGrupoId(2);
```

Por ultimo guardar el objeto tipo PersonaGrupo.

```
em = getEM();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(personasGrupos);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

No se si me he explicado bien.

Comment: Si se entiende bien. De igual manera lo que quisiera saber es si no se puede realizar eso mismo que hiciste pero aprovechando la relación ManyToMany bidireccional de los modelos. Así no tendré que crear un POJO para la union.
Lo que busco en otras palabras es que JPA me cree la consulta INSERT into PERSONAS_GRUPOS (ID_PERS, ID_GROUP) VALUES (?,?) pasando solo las id, para no hacer una consulta solo para cargar toda la info dentro del MODELO. No se si me explico.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que tendrás algo asi:

```
public class Personas{
private int id;
    private String nombres;
    private String apellidos;
    List<Grupos> grupos = new List() ;
} 
public class Grupos{
    private int id;
    private String nombGrupo;
    List<Personas> personas = new List() ;
}
```

Supongo que tendras los Getters() y Setters()
Creo que deberia ser algo así:

```
Grupos grup1 = new Grupos() ;
grup1.setId(1) ;
Grupos grup2 = new Grupos();
grup2.setId(2)
Personas pers = new Personas();
pers.setID(1);
pers.setGrupos().add(grup1);
pers.setGrupos().add(grup2);
```

Asegúrate de que en la base de datos los campos que no sean ID no sean NOT NULL.
Espero servir de ayuda

Comment: Edite la entrada principal para que puedas ver como tengo estructurado mi Entidad Java.